# Combine AdapterView with Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-adapterview

I have a navigation drawer in the MainActivity of my application.
In this activity, an AdapterView is set.
When I click one of the rows of the adapter, I want a new activity to be opened, but under the **same navigation drawer**:

```
searchResultList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class));
    }
});
```

Right now, the new activity (Details) is opened without showing the navigation drawer.

Please show me how to do it, without writing the code of navigation drawer for each activity...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that the `AdapterView` (more likely a list) is in the `navigation drawer` or do you have a 'List' in your `Activity` and when you go to the `DetailsActivity` you lose the *drawer*??

Answer (score 1):

Hey before you look at the answer you should watch this [Android dev Summit Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASO5gWb9Mhg), it will give you a good idea to what to do plus it has a new way of easily achieving a navigational  drawer layout.
For that you have two options, first and most preferable is to use `Fragments` instead of your `Activities` and have one `FragmentActivity` that has your `DrawerLayout` and a `FrameLayout` that will contain the `Fragment' view.

## FragmentActivity.java

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

Thats what is in the *Android* documentation for using `DrawerLayout` you can find it more in details [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

If you are wondering of how you can add `Fragments` to your `Activity` in code, here is what you have to do:

```
      FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      /*if you are using a FragmentActivity or an AppCompatActivity as
      your super class you'll need to use getSupportFragmentManager 
      method*/
      FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.YOUR_FRAMELAYOUT_ID, fragment, fargmentTag);
      /*Here you should add your frameLayout ID as your first argument
      Thats where your new fragment will reside on the screen its like
      an iframe.
      This will replace the current fragment shown in your frameLayout if any and 
      add the new one*/
      ft.addToBackStack(null);
      /*You can add your fragment to your backstack and assign a String value 
      as its key if you want to get back to it in the future*/
      ft.commit();
      //By commiting you apply the Fragment transaction and start 
      //drawing the Fragment on screen
```

---

The other option is to have a `Parent Activity` that has the code and view setup for the `DrawerLayout` and you extend from that `ParentActivity` in your `Activities`. You will also need to use have an `parent_activity.xml` that will have your `DrawerLayout` as the main tag and have a `ViewStub` to add each of your `Activity` view in it.

## parent_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/myActivityLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and here what your `ParentActivty` that you should inherit from should look like:

## ParentActivty.java

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parent_activity);
}

public void setUpChildActivityView(int childActivityView){
    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
    stub.setLayoutResource(childActivityView);
    View inflated = stub.inflate();
}}
```

You can call the `setUpChildActivtiyView()` method from your new `Activity` to set your content, you can also achieve the same result without using a `ViewStub` but with *inflating* and *adding* your new `Activity` view to the `ParentActivity` view using `addView()` method.

---

Personally i prefer the first option since its the convention that is there in the documentation, but you can do it either way.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I do use fragments in my navigation drawer, but I just could not understand how to open a new fragment (so I save the navigation drawer) from clicking on a button in the activity (not in the navigation drawer)...

Comment: Ok so you want to open the fragment in your activity. For example: if you have `ContactsFragment` displayed which has a list of contacts then you press one of them to display its details , so you lunch the `ContactDetailsFragment` with the contact details. Then your question is how to display different fragments in your activity??. Did I get that right??

Comment: Correct. And the navigation drawer will be accessible either I see the list or I see a contact details.

Comment: Sorry for answering after a week, but i updated the answer to include how you can add and replace your `Fragments` in a `FrameLayout` programmatically, hope it helps :)